# Synchronize servers clocks in a ring pattern

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, serversocket

i have a network architecture that consists of 5 servers that work in a ring layout: one way communication between them.I found myself in need to synchronize the time in these servers and can't find a way to do so in a one way communication pattern.
the reason i want to synchronize the clocks is to be able to measure the travel time between each of the servers.
i will only add that the servers sit in different domains.
is there a way to do that?
thanks in advance for all the helpers.

Comment: There is no such thing as a network with one-way communication.  You might be using a unidirectional protocol for some application, but the network itself must be capable of bidirectional communication.  The term "Travel Time" is ambiguous.  `ping` will give you the round-trip time for an ICMP packet.  TCP packets get there when they get there, as long as they don't outlive their TTL limits, but how long it takes will vary depending on network load.  Unidirectional UDP packets might have something you might call a "travel time"... what exactly are you talking about?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: First of all thanks for the help.I want to measure the time it takes a tcp packet with a specific size (let's say about 1KB) to go from one server to the other. I can't use ping or anything like that because the communication is unidirectional.

Comment: you are right i meant to say i am using udp packet, i will add the duration it took to the packet and send it to the next server until i  make a round trip.

Answer (score -1):

If you are waiting a hole trip (from comment), why not just keep the timestamps as is and measure when it gets back to start server?

EDIT:

One solution would be to run it two laps, then you could calculate lap times.

s1: 0
s2: 4
s3: 100
s1: 101
s2: 103
s3: 104

Then you can find out that in first lap s2 was slow by difference checking s2lap1 and s2lap2.

Comment: Because i want to know the time between each server to monitor changes and anomalies, perhaps there is a problem in one server that makes him work slower and because of that the whole round trip is delayed.

Comment: One solution would be to run it two laps, then you could calculate lap times.

s1: 0
s2: 4
s3: 100
s1: 101
s2: 103
s3: 104

Then you can find out that in first lap s2 was slow by difference checking s2lap1 and s2lap2.